# ajax submit dont showing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and found a problem that i can't solve. I have a form on index.html with a input "ID"  and a getdata.php that will use the ID to complete an url and use XPath to extract content of that url.

I want use ajax for that to avoid the page refresh (maybe this is not the best approach, I am open to other suggestions if this is the case) but nothing is showing when I hit the submit button, if I use the form without ajax it works fine.  My code is:

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('button[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.php",
                data: $("#getlist").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                      $('#list').html('<img src="728.GIF" />');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                      $('#list').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**form**

```
<form class="form form-inline form-multiline" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="" id="getlist">
   <br>
   <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4">
       <label for="id">ID</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="e.g 2071">
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">List</h3>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4" id="list" name="list"></div>
   <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
       <br>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Submit</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: have you checked your browser console / developer tools to see if there is an error?

Comment: is this the entire form code that you are using???

Comment: Can you post the PHP code for getdata.php?

Comment: use console.log(data); in the success function and look at the console what shows up?

Comment: In general you should give your <button> an ID and set its type to type="button". This way you'll be able to use the ID to handle the click event instead of searching for it via button[type=submit]. Going this route will also allow you to also remove the call to preventDefault() and your JavaScript and HTML will make more sense.

Comment: i can multipart form data but no input type other than text\

Comment: I did like Sean told and see a "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" even with jquery there, did a search here changed the order of jquery and worked fine, sorry guys. mikehomme thanks for the advice, i will do that.